# Set chart range and stop when there is empty cell

Tags: vba, charts

I am trying to plot a chart on my vba and setting the chart range. I want the chart range to end when there is an empty cell as I have a lot of data. However, it is not working. I am suppose to get a lot of points but i end up getting only one point. I checked the selected data from the chart and it turns out that the range is not the range I want but I typed the correct range. Thanks for your help.

```
 Set rng = Sheet2.range("I24", ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
 Set ach = Sheet3.Shapes.AddChart2
 ach.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
 ach.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
 ach.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Alignment"
 ach.Left = 200
 ach.Height = 400
 ach.Width = 600
```

Comment: where does your `rng` for chart starts ? is it from "I24" all the way down ?

Comment: yup until there is empty cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
With Sheet2
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("I24"), .Range("I24").End(xlDown))
ENd With
```